# Emscripten installation error: "./emcc no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, archlinux, emscripten

I tried installing Emscripten on the latest version Arch Linux but was unsuccessful. I recieved no errors during the installation process, but when I attempted to verify the installation it threw an error: `"bash: ./emcc no such file or directory"`. To the best of my ability I followed the instrcutions at https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html.

Installation Steps:

1) Dependencies (GCC ships complete with Arch, so no need to install)

```
pacman -S cmake python2 nodejs git
```

2) Download and unzip `emsdk-portable.tar.gz`

```
mkdir emscripten && cd empscripten
tar -xvf emsdk-portable.tar.gz
```

3) Installation

```
cd emsdk-portable
./emsdk update
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

source ./emsdk outputs:

```
Adding directories to PATH:
PATH += /home/myuser/emscripten/emsdk-portable

Setting environment variables:
EMSDK = /home/myuser/emscripten/emsdk-portable
EM_CONFIG = /home/myuser/.emscripten
```

Running `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/home/myuser/emscripten/emsdk-portable:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Running `./emcc -v` or `./em++ -v` outputs:

```
bash: ./emcc: No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts?

Here is my `~/.emscripten` file:

```
import os
SPIDERMONKEY_ENGINE = ''
NODE_JS = 'node'
V8_ENGINE = ''
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

Comment: what's the output of the command `which emcc` ?

Comment: Hello. It reads: 'which: no emcc in (/home/myuser/emscripten/emsdk-portable:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)'

Comment: i guess you need to follow those steps https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/building_emscripten_from_source_using_the_sdk.html

Answer (score 4):

Most usually, a current directory (`.`) is not added to the `PATH` variable, AFAIK it is for security reasons, so don't add it yourself too. :) When someone executes `./emcc`, they specify **the relative path** to the program to be executed: "a program `emcc` residing precisely **in the current directory**".

On the other hand, executing just `emcc` (without the `./` prefix) means "iterate through the directories from the `PATH` variable left-to-right and execute the first found `emcc` executable". When you `source` the `emsdk_env.sh` you, among other things, adjust the `PATH` variable.

In comments you told that `which emcc` cannot find the `emcc` executable. It is strange, but even when you manage to fix the installation problem, you have to most usually specify `emcc` on the command line **without** the `./` prefix.

Comment: Not clear on this. I’m on Linux. This is how we install it. https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki

Comment: In fact, first I have spotted that you write `./emcc` instead of `emcc`. This will lead to `command not found` unless `emcc` executable is in your current directory that is almost always not what you want, so I started explaining this. Just before sending the answer, I spotted your reply in comments that `emcc` is not found in the `PATH` too, so my answer alone will not solve your particular problem. But I have posted it anyway because when you will finally manage to get everything installed, you cannot run it with `./` prefix, so the answer will probably be useful on next step.

Comment: Your output of `source ./emsdk_env.sh` is quite strange: I have something like 4 lines `PATH += ...` and you have only one. Maybe you can try to navigate to `emsdk_portable` and execute `./emsdk activate latest` once more time (here with `./` in front, because the executable in question is really in the current directory and not in `PATH`), then `source ./emsdk_env.sh` again. If this will not help, I have no ideas other than reinstall or install from source (but this may be time and hard drive space consuming and I'm not sure it will help).